# Integrating definite integrals in terms of area

Tags: calculus

Lately, I've been trying to come up with tricks to solve integrals quickly.

So let's say I have $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta d\theta$$

Now if I were to look at this integral in polar coordiantes, I get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta d\theta$$

The integrand is a circle in polar coordinates $r = 2(1/2)\cos\theta$ with radius $1/2$

So the integral $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But this doesn't make sense to me because the area should be $\pi (1/2)^2 = \pi/4$

What's going on? I am trying to extend this idea to $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^2 \theta d\theta$$ and linear combinations of sine and cosines squared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral does not "know" that $r$ cannot be negative.  So from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$ it cheerfully keeps "adding  up" $\cos^2 \theta$, not realizing there is no curve there. Effectively the integral traverses the circle twice.

It really should know that the integration should be done from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$. Or equivalently that it should be integrating $\frac{1}{2}f^2(\theta)$, where $f(\theta)=0$ on $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$, and $f(\theta)=\cos\theta$ elsewhere on $[0,2\pi]$. But nobody told it.

**Remark:** There is not universal agreement that the point that has polar coordinates address $(r,\theta)$ makes no sense if $r \lt 0$. One **common** interpretation in that case is that you graph $(r,\theta)$ and then reflect the result across the origin. That interpretation sometimes produces nicer pictures.

If we take that interpretation, then $r=\cos\theta$ sweeps out our circle as $\theta$ travels from $0$ to $\pi$, so integrating from $0$ to $\pi$ gives the area.

Comment: Yeah, it adds up "0s" Doesn't from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$ it sweeps everything else?

Comment: The part from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$ is part of the "real" curve, since $\cos\theta$ is $\ge 0$ there.

Comment: What do you mean "real" part?

Comment: I mean the curve. The part with $r$ negative is not part of the curve. Actually, under a **popular** interpretation, $r$ negative is OK, but if you get that you reflect across the origin. With that interprtation you really do traverse the circle twice, once would be $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: @jak: Have you tried tracing out the curve in polar coordinates as you go through the values of $\theta$ within your integration domain? You're basically drawing over the curve anew, and the integration won't catch that.

Comment: OKay sorry for my belated reply. I tried tracing the circle from 0 to $\pi/2$ and it was okay. Then for $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ I get a semi-circle on the Quad II and from $\pi$ to $3\pi/2$ I get a semi-circle on Quad III and from $3\pi/2$ to $2\pi$ I get a semi-circle in Quad I. But the semi-circle back in Quad II gets reflected?

Answer (score 4):

$r = \cos \theta$ describes a circle for, say, $-\pi/2 \le r \le \pi/2$ (where $\cos \theta > 0$).
As $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2 \pi$, you go around the circle twice.